# Does $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]^\mathrm{int}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/easy-way-to-show-that-mathbbz-sqrt32-is-the-ring-of-integers-of-mat)

Is the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ equal to its integral closure in its quotient field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n})$?

I believe it would be enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a UFD, but I'm not sure if it's true. I approached this by attempting to show it is a Euclidean domain, but with a cube root, I couldn't think of a good norm.

Otherwise, I would take $\alpha/\beta$ in the quotient field, and multiply the equation
$$
(\alpha/\beta)^m+a_1(\alpha/\beta)^{m-1}+\cdots+a_m=0\qquad a_i\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]
$$
through by $\beta^m$. So if $p$ where any prime dividing $\beta$ and not $\alpha$ I would get a contradiction, so $\alpha/\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

I just don't know if this is the right approach though, since I can't show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is an Euclidean domain, PID, or UFD. Is there an obvious integral element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\setminus\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ that I'm missing to prove otherwise?\

**Edit**: Is it possible to conclude this without resorting to a lot of machinery from algebraic number theory and strictly using tools from commutative algebra? I didn't follow the answers in the duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, but it's not trivial to show. It would be enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a UFD, but I'm pretty sure it's not.

Comment: @Arturo I flagged for moderators' help for the same reason you edited the post. I couldn't edit it for some reason! Thanks anyway!