# $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},(\sqrt[3]{3})^2 \}$ is integral basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3^3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

prove that 
   $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},(\sqrt[3]{3})^2 \}$ is integral basis for $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3^3})$

my aim is to show that $\Bbb{Q}_K=\Bbb{Z}+\sqrt[3]{3}\Bbb{Z}+(\sqrt[3]{3})^2\Bbb{Z}$

$\supseteq$ : it is clear

$\subseteq$ : let $\alpha \in \Bbb{Q}_K$ i want to show $\alpha=z_1+z_2\sqrt[3] {3}+z_3(\sqrt[3]{3})^2$
 and  $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb{Z}$

is there any short way to show this ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: IMVHO your notation is a bit funny/inconsistent. If I guess that you want to look at the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of3)$? A good start is usually to look at the traces as integral elements have integral traces. If you calculate $\mathrm{tr}((\root3\of3)^i\alpha)$ for $i=0,1,2$ you will learn that $3z_i, i=1,2,3,$ are all in $\Bbb{Z}$. As $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a ring that (using the other inclusion) leaves you with the task of checking out the 27 possible combinations $z_i=\{0,1/3,2/3\}, i=1,2,3.$

Comment: @izaag: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/easy-way-to-show-that-mathbbz-sqrt32-is-the-ring-of-integers-of-mat