# Find the ring of algebraic integers.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Find the ring of algebraic integers in $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

So, I know that $K=\{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{2}^2 \mid a,b,c \in \mathbb Q\}$.

My professor has done very little on this topic. I know that an algebraic integer is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

I have no clue on where to start with this question. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: A good guess is to try $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. There depending of how much algberaic number theory you know will be easier or harder to prove.

Comment: See if this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/easy-way-to-show-that-mathbbz-sqrt32-is-the-ring-of-integers-of-mat) helps.

Comment: Are you familiar with the trace function?