# How to compute the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[n]{p})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, integral-dependence, integer-rings

We have the definition of integral closure that all the integral elements of *A* in *B*. Could we just compute the integral closure of certain *A* in *B*. I am considering such a problem that given a prime p, what is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^n–p)$.

After some trials, I find the answer maybe $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$, the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ should be the subset of the closure of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$. But $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ is generated by $1, s, s^2, \dots, s^{n–1}$ which are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. $s$ is the image of x modulo (x^n–p). Therefore $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now I want to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ is normal.
Assume that $u\in\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^n–p)$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ with a monic poly $f$. Since $\exists d \in\mathbb{Z}$ and $e\in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ s.t du–e=0. Then f can be divided by dx-e. Assume that $f=(dx-e)g$, where $g$ is a poly with leading coefficient h in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$.
Then we get $hd=1$. Since $d$ is a integer, $h$ has to be a integer too. This implies that $d=1$ or $–1$. Both sides implies $u\in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$. So we got the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$  contains $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n–p)$ which is exactly the closure of itself. Q.E.D

Is there any mistakes in the proof?

Comment: In general the question of finding the integral closure is quite subtle, and involves tools such as trace, discriminant et cetera. I use the definitive article, because the closure is unique in this instance.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you tell me how to solve this problem. I think it may need something concerned cyclic extension.

Comment: Cam McLeman is one of the practitioners of algebraic number theory. He is discussing the case $n=3$, $p=2$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/99913/11619), and says that this problem is difficult in general (to be honest he may be thinking about a bit more general problem, when the polynomial you mod out is not a binomial). I have no reason not to believe him. He **is** an expert. Use that as ammo against people who think you should be able to solve this easily. User26857 was right in that the special case $n=2$ is easy. The answer does depend on the residue class of $p$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Then again, user26857 is very knowledgeable about commutative algebra and its application to algebraic geometry. So if you were asking about integral closure inside a more geometrically originating ring, he would know of ways to relate integral closure to geometric properties.

Comment: @user26857 could we get the integral closure z[x]/(x^n–p) is the subset of the integral closure of z from it contains z[x]/(x^n–p)

Comment: The proposition after lemma 6 in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/182822) could be interesting for you.

Comment: You can read https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/integersradical.pdf. It is _not_ true that the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{2})$ is equal to $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ in general! This is true for $n=2, 3, 4$ and in fact for all $n \leq 1000$, but not for $n=1093$... !