# Simple way to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Leting $\delta:=\sqrt[3]{2}$, prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\delta]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\delta)$.

Here's what I've done: let $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\delta)$. Since $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$, then $1, \delta, \delta^2$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent (in particular, they are $\mathbb{Z}$-independent). Since $1, \delta, \delta^2$ are integers of $K$, we have that $\mathbb{Z}[\delta]=<1, \delta, \delta^2>_{\mathbb{Z}}\subset\mathcal{O}_{K}$.

To prove $\supset$, I did the following: if $z=a+b\delta+c\delta^2$ is an integer of $K$, its minimal polynomial $p(x)=x^3+c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and has roots $\sigma_1(z),\sigma_2(z)$ and $\sigma_3(z)$, where

\begin{align*} 
\sigma_1 &:\delta\mapsto\delta\\
\sigma_2 &:\delta\mapsto\omega\delta\\
\sigma_3 &:\delta\mapsto\omega^2\delta
\end{align*}

are the embeddings fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\omega^3=1$. Using Viète's relations we get:

\begin{align*} 
 c_2&=-\sum_{i}\sigma_i(z)= -3a\\        
 c_1&= \sum_{i<j}\sigma_i(z)\sigma_j(z)=3a^2-6bc\\
 c_0&= -\prod_{i}\sigma_i(z)=-(a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc)
\end{align*}

which gives us restrictions for $a, b, c$, since $c_0, c_1, c_2\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\delta z$ and $\delta^2 z$ are also integers of $K$, we calculate its respective minimal polynomials and find new restrictions for $a, b, c$.

After a very tiresome case analysis, I could prove that $a, b, c\in\mathbb{Z}$, concluding the proof.

This solution was given as a hint by the professor, and seems to me not very natural and, above all, way too long. My question is: is there a more natural and/or shorter solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/

Answer (score 1):

This from book algebraic number theory, J.S. MILNE, p.34

In general we have $\mathbb Z[\alpha] \subseteq O_k \subseteq d^{-1} \mathbb Z[\alpha] $ where $k=\mathbb Q[\alpha] , d=disc\{ 1,\alpha,...,\alpha^{n-1} \}$