# Finding an integral basis for a cubic field using the discriminant

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is sort of a revival of [this dead post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487510/how-to-prove-1-sqrt32-sqrt34-is-an-integral-basis-of-mathbbq) but with a few tangential questions that I don't feel like I should coattail onto the linked post. Suppose we are trying to find an integral basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha^{3}-2 = 0$. We find that $d = \text{disc}(\lbrace 1, \alpha, \alpha^{2} \rbrace) = -108 = -2^{2}3^{3}$ and since this isn't squarefree, we have more work to do if we're to show $\lbrace 1, \alpha, \alpha^{2} \rbrace$ is an integral basis. So, we can use the result that
$$ \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subset \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]} \subset d^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]. $$
Now, what I'd like to do is to show that for any $\beta \in d^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \setminus \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ we have $\beta$ is not integral. As per the linked post, we should only verify that $\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^{2}}{x}$ is not integral for $x=2,3$. **First question: why are these the only elements that we need to check?** It seems to me like we should check this for $\frac{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^{2}}{x}$ for $x | 2^{2}3^{3}$ and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$. **On top of that, is there a clever way to compute the norm of a generic element of $d^{-1}\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ that I'm missing, because I don't know how I'd go about this.**

Comment: Put $M = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha], K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, and let $d'$ be the discriminant of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$. We have the following relation between $d$ and $d'$: $d = [\mathcal{O}_{K}:M]^{2} \cdot d'$, so $[\mathcal{O}_{K}:M]$ must divide the largest possible square divisor of $-108$, namely $6$. As for computing the norm of a generic element, I don't know of any clever method, but a brute force approach *is* doable, and the result is not so bad.

Comment: (You might also look at the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/easy-way-to-show-that-mathbbz-sqrt32-is-the-ring-of-integers-of-mat. Dylan Moreland's answer makes the same observation that my comment does.)

Comment: The ring of integers of a pure cubic field is entirely known, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3508522/300700